# JPA - Ensure that no reservation has conflict with required reservation

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I am building a simple rentables reservation application for a project. Users may reserve homes if there are no other reservations conflicting with the required ones. 
I have two Entity classes - Rentable and Reservation 
Reservations have @ManyToOne relationships with rentables and 2 fields of interest - reserveFrom and reserveUntil. 
The problem is the following: 
Because I wish to provide paging functionality, I need a way to return chunks of responses, therefore an application level solution (that is, filtering by loading everything in memory and so on) is quite expensive. 
A user should be able to provide two dates (from, to), and chunks of available rentables are then returned. 
 
Any guidelines on how to implement this query? I can see the following cases: A Rentable is not available for a specific Reservation r1 if there is some other Reservation r2 belonging to the rentable such that 
r2.reserveFrom < r1.reserveFrom < r2.reserveUntil OR 
r2.reserveFrom < r1.reserveUntil < r2.reserveUntil OR 
r1.reserveFrom < r2.reserveFrom < r2.reserveUntil < r1.reserveUntil

A baseline query that I have thought of so far is the following (input: f (from), t (to))

```
SELECT DISTINCT rentable
FROM Rentable rentable JOIN Reservation reservation
WHERE NOT (f BETWEEN reservation.reserveFrom AND reservation.reserveUntil
OR t BETWEEN reservation.reserveFrom AND reservation.reserveUntil
OR (f > reservation.reserveFrom AND t < reservation.reserveUntil))
```

The problem with this is that just because one row passes the filter, that does not mean that the rentable should be returned (some other row might disqualify it). 
I feel like there has to be some EXISTS clause involved. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)  in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of exists is on target, more specifically not exists. It looks like you have the overlap coverage identified, there is no need, Postgres has built in operator for just that. Rather then working with individual dates combine both the table dates and the parameter dates into a [DATERANGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) then apply the [OVERLAP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator (&&). The result will be a list that does have overlaps. That goes into the NOT EXISTS predicate.

```
create or replace 
function available_rentables(from_date_in date, to_date_in date)
  returns setof rentable
  language sql
as $$
with request (parm_range) as 
     ( select  daterange ( from_date_in
                         , to_date_in
                         , '[]'
                         )    
     )   
select *
  from rentable  ren
 where not exists 
       (select null 
          from reservation res
          join request   
            on daterange(res.from_date, res.to_date) && parm_range
       );
$$;
```

The above gives you a list of rentables available for the period from_date, to_date range specified. The above assumes the ranges are inclusive of both endpoints. Also depending on overall usage you could store from_date, to_date columns reservations as a single daterange.  
As @a_horse_with_no_name suggests an exclusive constraint would be good insurance at the database level.